# Probability of gettting 0.0 from random()?

Tags: python, random, floating-point, probability-density

I'm trying to make a simple program to demonstrate something, though I'm a bit preplexed on the math of it.

```py
from random import random
a = random()
```

I read up on the random function and its distribution is [0.0;1.0). It uses Mersenne Twister to generate pseudo randoms and it's a 56bit precision floating number.

I'm assuming that means that the probability of it generating exactly 0.0 is 1/2^56?

What would a have to be lower than, in order for the probability to be 1/2^28?.. I tried understanding the 56-bit float conversion but I can't seem to figure it out. What would the actual float value have to be?

```py
a = ?
if random() < a:
  print("Success")
```

Comment: If the probability of generating 0.0 is 1/2^56, it does not mean that generating 2^56 random numbers would necessarily generate a 0.0.  As an alternate example, consider a coin toss.  Even though the probability of a head is 1/2, it does not mean that tossing the coin twice will necessarily yield a head.

Comment: Do you mean Mersenne Twister? Twisted nematic is an LCD technology, not a random number generator.

Comment: Yes Mersenne Twister. It's 3am and my brain is being weird, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a continuous uniform distribution over [0, 1), the portion of samples less than x is x. For example, ½ the samples are less than ½. So the x such that the probability that a sample is less than x is 1/2<sup>28</sup> is 1/2<sup>28</sup>.

With a quantized distribution (only multiples of a certain quantum are in the distribution) over [0, 1), the same is true if x is a number in the distribution. If it is between two numbers in the distribution, the probability a sample is less than x is the number just greater than x. However, in the situation you describe, it seems like 1/2<sup>28</sup> is in the distribution, and so it is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it was generated.  Almost all libraries use the equidistant method to produce values on [0,1).  Briefly:

1. Generate uniform integer (say 64-bits returned per call)
2. Throw away the number of excess bits to match the floating-point precision (24 for single, 53 for doubles)
3. Convert integer to float (no rounding occurs since value "fits") and scale to range (2^-24/2^-53)

So (taking doubles) the method produces 2^53 unique FP values and each occurs with probability of 2^-53.  The number of bits of the underlying integer generator doesn't effect this.